# Jquery Onchange event not getting fired - Primefaces - inputText

Tags: jquery, primefaces

The following event is not getting invoked:

```
<script>
        $("#inputTxt").change(function() {
            alert("changed");
        }); 
 </script>
```

The code for inputTxt is as follows:

```
<p:inputText id ="inputTxt" name="inputTxt" value="#{article.description}"
                    style="border:none; box-shadow:none;"/>
```

The coloumn "articleDescription" is defined in a datatable named "articlesInformation" which is placed on a form "articleForm".

On inspected the element, I found that the id of the inputText becomes - "articlesInformation:0:inputTxt". Probably that is the issue.

Viewing page info says :

```
    <td role="gridcell">
       <div class="ui-dt-c">
        <input id="articlesInformation:0:inputTxt" name="articlesInformation:0:inputTxt"
         type="text" value="Description of Article 1"
         style="border:none; box-shadow:none;"
         class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" />
       <script id="articlesInformation:0:inputTxt_s"
  type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw('InputText','widget_articlesInformation_0_inputTxt'
    {id:'articlesInformation:0:inputTxt'});
</script></div></td>
```

How should the jquery be defined for primefaces components?

Thanks,
Shikha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When inputText is placed in datatable, primefaces gives it id = datatable_id:row_index:inputText_id. That is, the inputText in row 7 is given the id = datatable_id:7:inputText_id. Try the below ...

```
<p:dataTable id="table_Details" var="dataItem" rowIndexVar="rowIndex">
     <p:column id="articleDescription" headerText="Article Description">
        <p:inputText id="inputTxt" name="inputTxt" value="#{article.description}" onchange="inputTextChanged(#{rowIndex})"/>
     </p:column>
</p:dataTable>

function inputTextChanged(rowIndex){
    var str = 'table_Details:' + rowIndex + ':inputTxt';
    var selected = $(document.getElementById(str));
    alert (selected.val());
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes it works :) Is it possible to change the background-color of the inputText in the method ?

Comment: try selected.style.backgroundColor = "#CC00CC";

Comment: selected.style is undefined. :( M I missing something. New to web programming. `function inputTextChanged(rowIndex){
     var str = 'articlesInformation:' + rowIndex + ':inputTxt';
     var selected = $(document.getElementById(str));
     
     alert( selected.style);
     selected.style.backgroundColor = "#CC00CC";
    
     alert ( selected.style);
 }`

Comment: `Name: <input type = "text" id="fname" name="fname" onchange="method1()" />  function method1(){
    
     var selected = (document.getElementById("fname"));
     selected.style.backgroundColor = "green";
 }` Here it works. Primefaces doing something ?

Comment: Use switchClass of jquery to conditionally switch style class of your inputText

Comment: $(document.getElementById(elementId)).css("background-color","green"); works

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [attributes ends with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

```
jQuery('input[id$="inputTxt"]').change(function() {
        alert("changed");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As the `id` of the element is being changed by Primefaces, you can use either the attribute selector to get the element by it's name (assuming that isn't changed either) or you could add a class to the element and select by that:

By attribute:

```
$("input[name='inputTxt']").change(function() {
    alert("changed");
});
```

By class:

```
$(".inputTxt").change(function() {
    alert("changed");
});
```

Comment: The name also gets updated in similar way. I tried adding class to the element like : `<p:inputText id="inputTxt" name="inputTxt" value="#{article.description}" styleClass="inputTxtCls" />' . but, its not working. Probably because the default class is not getting overridden. Inspecting the element shows class as `ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-state-hover`

Comment: @Shikha.Dhawan are you using some sort of jQuery UI component on the elemnt?

Comment: @Nicola Didn't get you. I have written the complete code in the question. Using the inputText as the value of a column of a primefaces' datatable

Comment: @Shikha.Dhawan He asked because the code you posted has classes with a prefix of `ui-`, which are generally used by jQuery UI. Could you please edit your question to include the HTML code which is output to the browser.

Comment: @Rory Updated the question. Using jquery & primefaces for the first time. Didn't know that.