# Primefaces how to update specific cell in dataTable in celleditor on dropdown value change?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have a datatable that uses the cell editor function. In each row, I have a dropdown and what I want is when a user chooses a different value in that dropdown, I want another cell in the current row to be updated.

Here's my column:

```
<p:column headerText="Period">
    <p:cellEditor>
        <f:facet name="input">
            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{pj_details.periodDates}" id="period" size="1" styleClass="listBoxMedium">
                <p:ajax update="tabs:editProjects:projects" event="change" listener="#{ppBacker.populateProjectDates}" />
                <f:attribute name="period_key" value="#{pj_details.periodDates}" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{ppBacker.periods}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>  
         </f:facet>
         <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="#{pj_details.periodDates}" />
         </f:facet>
    </p:cellEditor>
</p:column>
```

My update works except it updates the enter form which throws the table out of celleditor mode.

Using firebug, I can see that the update I need looks like this:

```
tabs:editProjects:projects:1:projStartDate_input
```

Only problem with that is the number 1 in this example refers to the row.

So how can i udpate a cell in the same row as the dropdown without being thrown out of celleditor mode?

Comment: just an idea... onsuccess of p:ajax use jquery selector to find the nearest "ui-icon ui-icon-pencil" using a class selector and then do .click() , something like this... jQuery(this).closest("tr").find('.ui-icon .ui-icon-pencil').click() that should enter you back into editing mode... havent tried it myself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the similar issue ...
[Jquery Onchange event not getting fired - Primefaces - inputText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9374651/jquery-onchange-event-not-getting-fired-primefaces-inputtext/9376806#9376806)

Define rowIndexVar for the datatable and access the cells with the help of rowIndexVar

Hope this helps